# Does an adjective 'polite' have 2 types of Degrees of comparison?

Tags: adjective-degrees

I read that 'polite' can have 2 ways of degree such as politer / politest and more polite / the most polite. Actually, I take the view of 2nd type because it's a long word, so we need to use more /the most. But if it's an the exception from the rule, when we should use the one form and another , or it doesn't matter and we can choose the form by our preference?

Comment: Even if it may be technically correct, I will leave it to others to give technical reasons for and against, but from an idiomatic stand point, I would never use "politer" or "politest" - it is very clunky. Definitely use "more polite" and "most polite" for everyday use.

Comment: @kettle_hands See, funnily enough I would use "more polite" but "politest" - using "the most polite" sounds very posh. E.g. "the politest of requests."

Comment: @kettle_hands "Clunky" is subjective. Certain words feel "clunky" simply because they're rarely used, (or in some cases commonly used but rarely heard by you). You have to prove the level of use objectively.

Comment: I'd be happy to. If you would be so kind as to point me in the right direction to find objective rules for idiomatic speech, I'll happily add them in. Many thanks!